# How can I access a laptop built-in camera?

Tags: macos, camera, realbasic

Is it possible to access the camera in a Macbook with REALbasic? I'd like to allow a user to capture an image from the camera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found 3 possible solutions:

1. a free plugin:
   [CamCapture](http://www.sourcemac.com/plugrb_CamCapture.dmg)
   This should work for anyone needing an easy method to capture images from the built-in iSight camera. It should also work for other QuickTime capable camera sources. There is an example project but no documentation. FYI- the site and example is in French.
2. Commercial option, which I wasn't able to try is [QTKit](http://www.monkeybreadsoftware.de/realbasic/plugin-qtkit.shtml) from MonkeyBread Software. This option is not free, but is documented and supported, unlike the free option.
3. [realcapture](http://sonicamigos.com/realcapture/) is a free, unsupported RB canvas. It uses declares to access the camera.